# writing a variable to text file using asp

Tags: html, asp-classic

hi looking for some help as I have hit a brick wall. I have a simple asp code that takes the content of a html file and writes to a text file ( see below). I can write strings to the file and everything works fine the problem occurs when I try to write one of the fields from the form.

```
sEmailAddress = request.form("IEmailAddress")

'** Now create the request file
Dim path, objFSO, objConn
path = "E:\Inetpub\sites\test\upd\"

'----- create output file
fileName = "Otest.wso"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(path & fileName, True)
w request.form("IEmailAddress")
outputFile.WriteLine("Start")
outputFile.WriteLine( request.form("IEmailAddress") )
outputFile.close
```

I can see the file being created and the word Start being written to the file. I also can see the emailaddress being displayed to the screen to make sure the data is being passed across to the file.

Answer (score 0):

either use your variable sEmailAddress  from your first line or correct the last line to the following:

```
outputFile.WriteLine( request.form("IEmailAddress") )
```

NOT

```
outputFile.WriteLine(request.form("sEmailAddress"))
```

( you have a typo in outputFile.WriteLine(request.form("sEmailAddress")) )

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I had typed into the post wrong. I have double checked the code from what you were saying but still having no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar a while back, which read from a text file and put the text file content into my text area. The user could then update what was in there and click "Update" and it would grab all the new information from the text area. Don't know if it is what you are trying to do, but my code is below. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE PAGE:**

```
    <!-- Opens / Creates the file Notifications.txt-->
        <%

            Set cs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set c=cs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("Notifications.txt"), 1)
            theGoods = (c.ReadAll)

            c.Close

            Set f=Nothing
            Set fs=Nothing


        %>
    <!-- /End the file Notifications.txt-->
        <form method="GET" action="overwrite.asp">

            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="Updates" id="Notifications" required><%= theGoods%></textarea>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" id="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('Update');"/>
            <input type="button" value="Bold Tags" id="bold" />
            <input type="button" value="Italic Tags" id="italic" />
        </form>
```

**Actual processing / overwrite page:**

```
<!-- Opens / Creates the file Notifications.txt-->
        <%
        Dim idea

        dim fs,f

        set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("Notifications.txt"), 2, true)

        idea= Request.QueryString("Updates")


        f.WriteLine(idea)
        f.Close
        set f=nothing
        set fs=nothing

        %>
```